# How to change default `pyproject.toml` that is generated when running `poetry new`

Tags: python-poetry

When I run `poetry new [directory]` it generates a `pyproject.toml` in the directory but I always find that I make the same initial changes to it such as

- the python version (from 2.7 to 3.8)
- the pytest version (from 4.6 to 5.4)

How can I change these defaults so that when I run `poetry new` python and pytest will have my desired versions?

Is the python version specified in the `pyproject.toml` based on the system's python version? If that is the case, I don't think I can change my system's python version since I am using a mac and it might mess up my OS. Or can I?

Comment: usually you'd write your own [cookie cutter](https://github.com/cookiecutter/cookiecutter), and use that instead. I don't think `poetry new` is supposed to be configured, it's just there to get beginners started quickly without having to jump through all the hoops at once.

Comment: @Arne Good to know. If you create an answer saying what you said there, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way to create project templates in python is with the [`cookiecutter`](https://pypi.org/project/cookiecutter/) utility. Its documentation is quite good and you can get started creating your own templates easily, but I'll give a short intro using the example you gave.

Cookiecutter uses a template language that allows you to specify which parts of your project template can be parametrized. In your case, that would be the project name (freely choosable) and maybe also the python & pytest versions (from a list of values). This information will be stored in a file called `cookiecutter.json` (some more examples on how that file can look [here](https://cookiecutter.readthedocs.io/en/1.7.0/tutorial1.html#cookiecutter-json)), that should look more or less like this:

```
{
    "full_name": "<your name>",
    "email": "<your name>@<email>.com",
    "project_name": "default",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "python_version": ["3.8", "2.7"],
    "pytest_version": ["5.4", "4.6"]
}
```

Now you need to:

- run `poetry new my_cookie` to create the base for the template
- put the `cookiecutter.json` into the resulting folder
- replace all mentions of the project name under the top-level folder with `{{cookiecutter.project_name}}`, including files and directories
- repeat that step for all other parameters in `cookiecutter.json`
- if you're done, create a project from your template by running `cookiecutter path/to/my_cookie`
- if you get stuck, take a look at [this sample project template](https://github.com/audreyr/cookiecutter-pypackage) or the docs I linked for guidance